# Exporting Python List to CSV in "column" format

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

right now I have Python 3 code that takes a column of data within a CSV file and then delimits the phrases in each cell into individual words based on spaces.

What I am trying to do now is export that data back into a CSV file in Column format so that it looks like this with each cell containing one word

```
Keyword
Lions
Tigers
Bears
Dog
Cats
```

Right now, my code exports the data to a CSV file but instead of coming in as a column format, it comes through in rows.

```
Keyword    Lions    Tigers     Bears     Dog    Cats
```

When I print my code in the interpreter, it comes through correctly in a column format but not when I export it!  Here is my code

```
with open(b'C:\Users\j\Desktop\helloworld.csv', 'r') as datafile:
    data = []
    for row in datafile:
        data.extend(item.strip() for item in row.split())
with open('test.csv', 'w') as a_file:
    for result in data:
        result = ''.join(result)
        a_file.write(result + ',')
        print(result)
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to transpose the data?  Thank you!

Comment: What is `data`? Could you add the output of `print(data)` to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
"\n"
```

to make it written in the next row.

```
with open(b'C:\Users\j\Desktop\helloworld.csv', 'r') as datafile:
  data = []
  for row in datafile:
    data.extend(item.strip() for item in row.split())
with open('test.csv', 'w') as a_file:
  for result in data:
    result = ''.join(result)
    a_file.write(result + '\n')  <--
    print(result)
```

Comment: fantastic -- simple and effective!

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.3, Python has had [a builtin module for parsing csv data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).  Is there any reason you can't use that?

To give an answer, specifically on your code, though, here's what I notice:

```
    a_file.write(result + ',')
    print(result)
```

You're writing the data to the file appended with a comma, and printing it to the command line separately. So it shows up on the command line with one output on each line, but it's getting printed to the file as:

```
result1,result2,result3,result4...
```

All CSV files are slightly different, but commas generally delimit fields, while newlines delimit rows. You're getting exactly what you're outputting: one row with all of your values on it, in separate comma-delimited fields.  Try this instead:

```
    a_file.write(result + '\n')
```

If you're in Python 3, then you can also use the print function:

```
    print(result, file=a_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `result`looks like, but I would say that you need to specify that you want to go to next line :

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as a_file:
    for result in data:
        result = ''.join(result)
        a_file.write(result + ',') # if you want to keep the coma, or replace ',' by '\n'
        a_file.write("\n")
        print(result)
```

However, it's weird you don't get coma in your output, hope this helps anyway.